# On line 138 of my code I keep getting an "expected a ';'" error (code E0065). I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition

Tags: c++, syntax-error, synthesizer

I've included all the code I've written so far, because I wasn't sure if anyone wanted to try to replicate the error. It might be too much, but I didn't want to leave anything out in case that's what was causing the error.

#include

```
using namespace std;

#include "olcNoiseMaker.h"
```

The line above shows what library I'm using, here's a link to the Github page where I got it from: https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/synth

```
//Converts frequency (Hz) to angular velocity
double w(double dHertz)
{
 return dHertz * 2.0 * PI;
}

atomic<double> dFrequencyOutput = 0.0;
double dOctaveBaseFrequency = 220.0; //A3
double d12thRootOf2 = pow(2.0, 1.0 / 12.0);
sEnvelopeADSR envelope;

double osc(double dHertz, double dTime, int nType)
{
    switch (nType)
    {
    case 0: // Sine Wave
        return sin(w(dHertz) * dTime);

    case 1: // Square Wave
        return sin(w(dHertz) * dTime) > 0 ? 1.0 : -1.0;

    case 2: // Triangle Wave
        return asin(sin(w(dHertz) * dTime)) * 2.0 / PI;

    case 3: // Saw Wave (analogue / warm / slow)
        {
            double dOutput = 0.0;

            for (double n = 1.0; n < 100.0; n++)
                dOutput += (sin(n * w(dHertz) * dTime)) / n;

           return dOutput * (2.0 / PI);
        }

    case 4: // Saw Wave (optimised / harsh / fast)
        return (2.0 / PI) * (dHertz * PI * fmod(dTime, 1.0 / dHertz) - (PI / 2.0));

    case 5: // Psuedo Random Noise
        return 2.0 * ((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX) - 1.0;

    default:
        return 0.0;
    }
}

struct sEnvelopeADSR
{
    double dAttackTime;
    double dDecayTime;
    double dReleaseTime;

    double dSustainAmplitude;
    double dStartAmplitude;

    double dTriggerOnTime;
    double dTriggerOffTime;

    bool bNoteOn;

    sEnvelopeADSR()
    {
        dAttackTime = 0.01;
        dDecayTime = 0.01;
        dStartAmplitude = 1.0;
        dSustainAmplitude = 0.8;
        dReleaseTime = 0.02;
        dTriggerOnTime = 0.0;
        dTriggerOffTime = 0.0;
        bNoteOn = false;
    }

    // Call when key is pressed
    void NoteOn(double dTimeOn)
    {
        dTriggerOnTime = dTimeOn;
        bNoteOn = true;
    }

    // Call when key is released
    void NoteOff(double dTimeOff)
    {
        dTriggerOffTime = dTimeOff;
        bNoteOn = false;
    }

    // Get the correct Amplitude at the requested point in time
    double GetAmplitude(double dTime)
    {
        double dAmplitude = 0.0;
        double dLifeTime = dTime - dTriggerOnTime;

        if (bNoteOn)
        {
            // ADS

            // Attack
            if (dLifeTime <= dAttackTime) {
                dAmplitude = (dLifeTime / dAttackTime) * dStartAmplitude;
            }

            // Decay
            if (dLifeTime > dAttackTime && dLifeTime <= (dAttackTime + dDecayTime)) {
                dAmplitude = ((dLifeTime - dAttackTime) / dDecayTime) * (dSustainAmplitude - dStartAmplitude) + dStartAmplitude;
            }

            // Sustain
            if (dLifeTime > (dAttackTime + dDecayTime))
            {
                dAmplitude = dSustainAmplitude;
            }
            else
            {
                // Release
                dAmplitude = ((dTime - dTriggerOffTime) / dReleaseTime) * (0.0 - dSustainAmplitude) + dSustainAmplitude;
            }

            if (dAmplitude <= 0.0001)
            {
                dAmplitude = 0;
            }

            return dAmplitude;
        }

    }

}

    // Function used by olcNoiseMaker to generate sound
    // Returns amplitude(-1.0 to + 1.0) as a function of time
    
    double MakeNoise(double dTime)
```

The line above is where I'm having the problem. In Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition, I get an error saying that a semicolon is needed somewhere before it. I don't understand the issue

```
    {

    }

        int main()
    {

        wcout << "onelonecoder.com - Synthesizer Part 1" << endl;

        // Get all sound behaviors
        vector<wstring> devices = olcNoiseMaker<short>::Enumerate();

        //Display findings
        for (auto d : devices) wcout << "Found Output Device:" << d << endl;

        // Create sound machine!!
        olcNoiseMaker<short> sound(devices[0], 44100, 1, 8, 512);

        // Link noise function with sound machine
        sound.SetUserFunction(MakeNoise);

        while (1)
        {
            //Add a keyboard like a piano
            bool bKeyPressed = false;
            for (int k = 0; k < 15; k++)
            {
                if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned char)("ZSXCFVGBNJMK\xbcL\xbe\xbf"[k])) & 0x8000)
                {
                    dFrequencyOutput = dOctaveBaseFrequency * pow(d12thRootOf2, k);
                    envelope.bNoteOn(sound.GetTime());
                    bKeyPressed = true;
                }
            }

            if (!bKeyPressed)
            {
                envelope.bNoteOff(sound.GetTime());
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"I didn't want to leave anything out in case that's what was causing the error."* -- ah, but you can test that, Make a copy of your code, remove stuff, and compile. If the error did not disappear, then the stuff you removed is not causing the error. Around here, we call that making a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I think I've talked to you before. That also sounds like a good method; I'll try it out next time I've had any sort of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end of a `struct` or `class` definition needs a `;` after it, even though it ends with a `}`.  This is one of those mistakes you usually only make once.

The reason for this is so that you can simultaneously declare the struct/class and create a variable of that type, by putting the variable name before the `;`.  This was used more often in C, you don't see it so much in C++.

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't have caught that being a mostly a beginner at C++. It always seems like the simple errors are the ones that muck me up, leaving me poring over my code for hours on end.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the semi-colon after that final `}` of your `struct osc` definition.